# How to load resources based on link in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to create a web application using react in which I want to load a page based on the link used, But I know that in react whenever you visit a direct link the entire app is reloaded and you have to navigate to that page using buttons or links provided in the app, I want to generate a temporary link for users which will contain the information about the data to be provided which the back end will check and retrieve from database and provide to the front end, This link will have a duration like for 24 hrs or something and will have an auth token, Can anyone please help me with how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

[React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) is a library that can handle this type of operation and is used in many, many apps. Among other things, it can parse URLs and render different content based on the URL, query parameters, and more.